# How to use a dictionary to loop through multiple urls with Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Alright I have created a web scraper.  I am quite new to python so if you have any other advice for me that would be awesome.

Basically my question is, how do I iterate through each of the dictionary items.  Basically the url = (common url) + (value in dictionary).  I want to go through each value in dictionary and then output it to csv.

Just a note:  If nothing has been posted by the company today then there will be no output to CSV For Sept 12(today) the only company that should output anything is "Ackroo": "00018766".

Thanks

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import time
import csv

links_list = []
other_list = []
time = time.strftime("%b %d %Y")


company_dict = {
    "Baytex Energy": "00031017",
    "Crescent Point Energy": "00028658",
    "Legacy Oil + Gas": "00023400",
    "Leucrotta Exploration": "00036173",
    "Lightstream Resources": "00028969",
    "Pengrowth Energy": "00031000",
    "Surge Energy": "00010447",
    "Ackroo": "00018766"
}

url = 'http://www.sedar.com/DisplayCompanyDocuments.do?lang=EN&issuerNo=%s' % (company_dict['Ackroo'])
sedar = urllib2.urlopen(url)
read_sedar = sedar.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(read_sedar)




def print_list():
    tds = soup.find_all('td')
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[0:len(tds)-1]]
        for x in row[4:]:
            other_list.append(row)
    return other_list


def get_links():
    html = 'http://www.sedar.com'
        for form in soup.find_all('form'):
        links_list.append(html + form.get('action'))
    return links_list

def write_to_output():
    text = print_list()
    get_links()
    text = [[s.strip() for s in inner] for inner in text[1:]]
    for a in text:
        a.remove('')
    i = 0
    with open('sedar.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
        for b in text:
            if b[0] == time:
                writer.writerow(['Surge'])
                writer.writerow(text[i])
                writer.writerow([links_list[i]])
                writer.writerow('')
                i = i + 1
            else:
                print "done"
                break

write_to_output()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you need to know is how to use methods properly. by the way, does your code work?

Answer (score 1):

I've reorganised your code a bit, and I *think* it will do what you want, but I haven't tested it because I don't have  Beautiful Soup installed.

```
company_dict = {
    "Baytex Energy": "00031017",
    "Crescent Point Energy": "00028658",
    "Legacy Oil + Gas": "00023400",
    "Leucrotta Exploration": "00036173",
    "Lightstream Resources": "00028969",
    "Pengrowth Energy": "00031000",
    "Surge Energy": "00010447",
    "Ackroo": "00018766"
}

base_url = 'http://www.sedar.com/DisplayCompanyDocuments.do'

def get_other(soup):
    other_list = []
    tds = soup.find_all('td')
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[0:len(tds)-1]]
        for x in row[4:]:
            other_list.append(row)
    return other_list


def get_links(soup):
    links_list = []
    html = 'http://www.sedar.com'
    for form in soup.find_all('form'):
        links_list.append(html + form.get('action'))
    return links_list


def write_to_output(writer, today, other_list, links_list):
    text = [[s.strip() for s in inner] for inner in other_list[1:]]

    for a in text:
        a.remove('')

    i = 0
    for b in text:
        if b[0] == today:
            writer.writerow(['Surge'])
            writer.writerow(text[i])
            writer.writerow([links_list[i]])
            writer.writerow('')
            i = i + 1
        else:
            print "done"
            break


def main():
    today = time.strftime("%b %d %Y")

    with open('sedar.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile)

        for company, issuerNo in company_dict.items():
            url = '%s?lang=EN&issuerNo=%s' % (base_url, issuerNo)
            print '%-25s : %s' % (company, url)

            sedar = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            read_sedar = sedar.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(read_sedar)

            other_list = get_other(soup)
            links_list = get_links(soup)

            write_to_output(writer, today, other_list, links_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It works perfectly after a few very minor tweaks.  Your code has taught me a lot in regards to how to better set up a web scraper.  Thanks

Comment: @WylieJohnston: You're welcome! Perhaps you should post your final version of the code here, too.

Answer (score 0):

If your question reduces to "How do I iterate through dictionary items?" then it's like this:

```
for k,v in d.items():
   print "%s -> %s"%(k,v)
```

There are alternatives like `d.iteritems()` and `d.viewitems()` which may be preferable in some situations, but they can all be used as above.

Comment: I know how to iterate through dictionary items, my problem is how do I create a loop that uses the first dictionary item, pulls the url, finds the data i need writes it to a csv then moves on to the next dictionary item.  The way it is right now it only works for a single company/dictionary item

Comment: You should probably put that in your question then. It says: "Basically my question is, how do I iterate through each of the dictionary items."